# Creating table with insert command to recreate every row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table named workerTab:

```
| Id | Name | Age | Cityid | 
| ---| ---- | --- |  ---   | 
| 1| John   | 22  | 5      |
| 2| Adam   | 34  | 5      |
| 3| Eve    | 19  | 5      |
```

And I would like to have in column: Build, insert query that will rebuild/fill my table.
I have something like that:

```
SELECT *
    ,CONCAT (
        'INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid)
VALUES(1, ''John'', 22, 5),'
        ,'(2, ''Adam'', 34, 5), '
        ,'(3, ''Eve'', 19, 5)'
        ) as Build
from workerTab
where cityid = 5
```

This is what I got :

| Id | Name | Age | Cityid | Build |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 22 | 5 | INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid) VALUES(1, 'John', 22, 5),(2, 'Adam', 34, 5), (3, 'Eve', 19, 5) |
| 2 | Adam | 34 | 5 | INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid) VALUES(1, 'John', 22, 5),(2, 'Adam', 34, 5), (3, 'Eve', 19, 5) |
| 3 | Eve | 19 | 5 | INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid) VALUES(1, 'John', 22, 5),(2, 'Adam', 34, 5), (3, 'Eve', 19, 5) |

I would like to have in column Build insert command for every row. For example:

| Id | Name | Age | Cityid | Build |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 22 | 5 | INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid) VALUES(1, 'John', 22, 5) |
| 2 | Adam | 34 | 5 | INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid) VALUES(2, 'Adam', 34, 5) |
| 3 | Eve | 19 | 5 | INSERT INTO workerTab(id,name,Age,Cityid) VALUES(3, 'Eve', 19, 5) |

I just got stuck and can't get it done.

Comment: Aside: `Age` is a rather unstable property for people. Calculating the current value from some sort of `InstanceCreationDate` is more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the insert for each row using values only from that row.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Age, Cityid,
       'INSERT INTO workerTab (Id, Name, Age, Cityid) VALUES (' +
       CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + QUOTENAME(Name, '''') + ', ' +
       CAST(Age AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ', ' + CAST(Cityid AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' AS Build
FROM workerTab
WHERE cityid = 5;
```